# Mobile AppRequests dialog only loading for developer

Tags: facebook, web-applications, mobile, apprequests

I am creating a mobile web app, and the friend request dialog works perfectly for me. But when my friend tries to do the app request, the dialog page starts, but gets stuck on loading and never works.  Updated info - This only happens on mobile - tested the iphone and safari (with iphone user agent)...when tested in a website browser it works good for my friend.

Here is the code I used, and I am not getting any errors - it just hangs:

```
 function sendRequest() {
  FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'invites you to share real-time availability',
  }, 
  function(response) {
    console.log('sendRequest response: ', response);

  });
}
```

Has anyone else seen this issue? Appreciate any help!

Thanks,
Renee

Comment: If you can post what code you've tried, and also any error messages and stack traces in your question, it might help get more traction for your question.

Comment: Thanks DMCS - I added the code now.

Answer (score 0):

From the above code, it appears you're missing the init(), login(), getLoginStatus() calls for the second user.  It works with you because you may have already granted access to your app.

See:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

and

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

Comment: Hi DMCS. So sorry for the delay - long story short - we have been trying to create a few user accounts to test a theory.(I am newbie)

We do have the code you mentioned. Strange thing-I just tested again for the profile where the apprequest was getting hung-up, and now it worked...my theory was wrong (timeline profile). Now facebook says I got some new error and is not letting me log out..geeez.

I am trying to create a startup and may need outside help....have any recommendations? I have a prototype UI built using jquery mobile, but would prefer to have it built using objective-c.
Thanks!!!